# Pythonic way of finding ways of walking through consecutive larger and larger lists

Tags: python, list, combinations

List number n contains 0 to n-1

```
l1 = [0]
l2 = [0,1]
l3 = [0,1,2]
```

I am looking to find possible combinations of these lists. The example above should yield

0 0 0 
0 0 1 
0 0 2 
0 1 0 
0 1 1
0 1 2

How would one do this in an efficient and pythonic way.

Comment: why is 002 not printed?

Comment: shouldn't this be your expected output?   ```010
002
011
012
001
000```

Comment: I'm not sure from the question as written what your combinatoric objective is. Could you rephrase? Do you actually desire non-unique outputs (I see 011 listed two times)?

Comment: @HarshGupta, you are right. Fixed the expected output!

Comment: Given a list of lists of sparse varying sizes, ie. the "original collection".  Generate a full list of list where each list is the size of the max list in the original collection and 0 is the default for all element of a list less then the max size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

loop on the lists and also keep a set so that you do not get repeated output

```
seen = set()
l1 = [0]
l2 = [0,1]
l3 = [0,1,2]
for i in l1:
    cur = [str(i)]
    for j in l2:
        cur.append(str(j))
        for k in l3:
            cur.append(str(k))
            seen.add("".join(cur))
            cur.pop()
        cur.pop()
for i in seen:
    print(i)
```

using itertools

you can use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
import itertools
l = [[0],[0,1],[0,1,2]]

print(list(itertools.product(*l)))
```

Comment: but this is only practical when the number of lists are small

Comment: @HaakonA check the updated ans